# Using Arrays of resources in Jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena, ontology

I need to read CSV file and then populate an ontology using jena and java. Since I need to reference some resources later in code, I created Arrays of resources such as the one below:

```
Resource [] singular_process= new Resource[1000];
singular_process[k] = model.createResource(URI + "singular_process"+i);
```

Where `i` is UUID

while reading the file, `k` represents record number, assume I made triples using the ontology such as:

```
Statement S1 = model.createStatement(singular_process[k],RDF.type,control);
model.add(S1);
```

and I made more triples using the same `singular_process[k]` and write its statements.
such as

```
Statement S2 = model.createStatement(singular_process[k],go:count,numbers);
model.add(S2);
```

the above two statements for the same file record

then I read another record and and `k` in `singular_process[k]` is different from the first one, do the same as in above create triplesfor this record and write them and so on.

My question, is this approach gives correct results since my `n3` file combines data from both above resources  which something I can't understand how that happens!

Second questions how to reference the above two defined resources later in code to merger them as if they have some common information saying that each one will be a member of new big process, how to reference them?

Do I need to make Statements as an Array as well?

Any other approaches that may give correct answer.

Comment: I can't actually tell what you are trying to do, which makes it next to impossible to answer the question. I can tell from code like `model.createResource(URI + "singular_process"+i)` that you haven't really understood your problem yet. Please update your question to show the actual **problem you are trying to solve**. E.g: a minimal set of lines from your CSV together with the RDF triples you expect to create from them.

Answer (score 0):

As Ian wrote in his comment, your question isn't completely clear.

However, having done some data conversion myself from CSV, TSV and tabular data, recently I'll try to provide you with some guidance, at least.

When you convert data from a CSV file to RDF you normally process one line at the time independently. For each line you need to decide what the subject will be and generate appropriate property URIs from the column names, values and/or some mapping/configuration file. Same for the objects/literals of your statements.

It is rare you need values from previous lines to process the current line. However, sometimes this is the case.

When this happened to me, rather than using additional data structures, such as Resource[] in your question, I use the Jena Model via Jena APIs or SPARQL queries to read the information I need. I don't consider it a best practice, ideally you want to process each line independently, however, when needed it works nicely. My Jena Model is backed up by TDB, so this works quite well even when your dataset does not fit entirely in RAM (however, it is not as fast as processing one line at the time independently).

Processing each line independently also is a pre-condition to write a MapReduce implementation of your data conversion. This is another good reason to avoid it if at all possible.

One way to void it is to pay some cost, initially, to sort your data or do an initial pass over it. This is not always possible though.

To conclude and recap: avoid using additional data structure, write your RDF data into a Jena model and use that to read previously generated data.